# Python List Duplication

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm fairly new to Python and StackOverflow, so forgive me for my terrible formatting. I had a question about duplicating rows in a DataFrame. I have a data set that looks like this.

| WEIGHT | AGE | DEBT | ASSETS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 34 | 4000 | 10000 |
| 3 | 42 | 3000 | 4000 |

I would like to duplicates the rows by the WEIGHT, so I will end up with the following:

| WEIGHT | AGE | DEBT | ASSETS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 34 | 4000 | 10000 |
| 2 | 34 | 4000 | 10000 |
| 3 | 42 | 3000 | 4000 |
| 3 | 42 | 3000 | 4000 |
| 3 | 42 | 3000 | 4000 |

I don't have a clue where to start and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html#pandas-index-repeat) and then reindex the dataframe:

```
print(df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df["WEIGHT"])))
```

Prints:

```
   WEIGHT  AGE  DEBT  ASSETS
0       2   34  4000   10000
0       2   34  4000   10000
1       3   42  3000    4000
1       3   42  3000    4000
1       3   42  3000    4000
```